# How to overlap a CSS background over an <img> tag?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an `<img>` tag inside an `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="urlPage" class="contain-video">
  <img src="urlImage" />
</a>
```

The `<a>` tag has the "contain-video" class, so I want to overlap a background image over the actual image:

```
//css file
.contain-video img {
    background: url('images/contain-video.png') no-repeat !important;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

but the background image is not shown. Any idea of how to achieve it?

Comment: A BACKGROUND image cannot be on top of an element...that's why it's called a background image.

Comment: Perhaps if you give a bit more detail; what you're trying to do, why your HTML is structured that way; we could offer an alternative that would make more sense?

Comment: if you're looking to just put an image that when someone clicks you can do what Stack exchange does at the top of your screen, they just put a background on the a tag.

Comment: @Paulie_D - All right. It's actually obvious. Any idea to achieve that behavior?

Comment: @Katana314 - I just want to overlap an image over the `<img>` image.

Comment: @Manolo Salsas What exactly is it you are trying to do. Why are you using multiple images?

Comment: You can post to images within the same ahref then set both of them to have an absolute position. Then on the css selector have the last one have a higher z-index than the first. Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/2nGun/

Comment: Actually you could have an img then a div rather than use two images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To overlap an element on top of a child element, using css only, you can use the pseudo-elements `:before` or `:after`

http://jsfiddle.net/LpkwH/2/

```
.image-link {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;   
    margin: 10px;
}

.contain-video:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(http://www.labiennale.org/img/play_icon.png);
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="urlPage" class="image-link">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxrvTJX_MbF6LInvYHSMteauE-NBolAQjBT82zVuLFqECGmut67A" />
```

```
<a href="urlPage" class="image-link contain-video">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxrvTJX_MbF6LInvYHSMteauE-NBolAQjBT82zVuLFqECGmut67A" />
```

Comment: This also has solid cross-browser compatibility, here is a [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter) to to caniuse.com for these pseudo elements.

Comment: Nice use of pseudo-elements. Technically `::after` is also acceptable (and the "correct" usage in CSS3), and depending on how browser support goes in the future you may need to include both if for whatever reason browser developers decide to stop supporting the old single-colon style for pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could supply an overlay div with image background inside the anchor tag, with `position: relative` for the tag and `position: absolute` for the inner div and making the inner div fit its parent (as long as the `a` is set to `display: block`, as that's normally an inline element and thus it does not expand to contain the `img`, which is providing the size for the overlay).

See this fiddle for an example (hovering over the overlay div shows what's below): http://jsfiddle.net/wz7mx/3/

Note that there is no need to explicitly set z-index.

Comment: Thanks, but with @CodeToad answer I don't have to change the `position` rule. This is an inconvenient for me.